# Show that shift operator in $L^p(\mathbb{R}) \to L^p(\mathbb{R})$ is bounded and compute its norm.

Tags: functional-analysis

> Let $1 < p < \infty$. Show that for some $s \in \mathbb{R}$ shift operator in $L^p(\mathbb{R}) \to L^p(\mathbb{R})$ defined as $L_s(f(x)) = f(x - s)$ is bounded and compute its norm.

---

Fix s and:
$$
\|L_s\| = \sup_{\|f\|_{L^p}=1} \| L_s(f(x))\|_{L^p} = \sup_{\|f\|_{L^p}=1} \left(\int_\mathbb{R} |f(x-s)|^pdx\right)^{\frac{1}{p}} =
$$
let $x-s = y; dx = dy$
$$
= \sup_{\|f\|_{L^p}=1} \left(\int_\mathbb{R - s} |f(y)|^pdy\right)^{\frac{1}{p}} = 1
$$
So $L$ is bounded and its norm is 1.

I feel like it was too straightforward and there's a mistake somewhere. Could anyone check and give the correct answer? Thank you.

Comment: Be careful, after the substitution, the $\sup$ goes over $\{f(\cdot-s):\, \|f\|_{L^p}=1\}$ and this is, a priori, not the same set as $\{f(\cdot):\, \|f\|_{L^p}=1\}$

Comment: You can argue this way: $L_s$ preserves norm of every function. This means that the norm is exactly 1